# How to get innerHTML of find_elements (not find_element) with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

My goal is to get this price text (2078--as shown in the pic), it works with find_element but the values in the output would be the same across the loop.

[image]
[image]

heres my code:

#Extracting the information from the results
for entry in entries:
#Empty list
labels=[]
#Extracting the Name, adress, Phone, and website:

```
name= entry.get_attribute("aria-label")
adress = entry.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="QA0Szd"]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/jsl[1]/div[2]')
adress_get = adress.get_attribute('innerHTML')


phone = entry.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'xwpmRb.qisNDe').text
try:
    webcontainer= entry.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'W4Efsd')
    website="Hello"
except NoSuchElementException:
    website="No website could be found"
print (name)
print (adress_get)
print (phone)
print (website)
```

My goal is to get list prices text from google map page (Web Scraping).

Comment: If this code is not working as you want, please explain.  Are you getting errors?  Are you getting unexpected output?

Comment: Im getting 'list' object has no attribute 'get_attribute' Error if I use find_elements but if I use only find_element it runs but the value does not iterate.

Comment: That's because `find_element` returns a single element, which does have a `.text` attribute.  But `find_elements` returns a _list_ of elements, and lists do not have a `.text` attribute.  You would have to look at the `.text` attribute of each element in the list.

Comment: Post the exact URL you are using.

Answer (score 1):

To print all the texts of all the elements found by `find_elements` you need to do the following:

```
phones = entry.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'xwpmRb.qisNDe')
for phone in phones:
    print(phone.text)
```

Or you can create a variable that holds elements' texts using this list comprehension:

```
phones = entry.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'xwpmRb.qisNDe')
phones_texts = [phone.text for phone in phones]
```

And then you can do whith it what you want, e.g. print the list or each element:

```
print(phones_texts)
# OR
for text in phones_texts:
    print(text)
```